# OBSOLETE - StackOverflow Updater.. Update Questions without the refresh

Tags: app, obsolete, javascript, chrome-extensions, google-chrome

> ## Obsolete: App is long gone from the Chrome store. No source-code available.  It was coded for a decommissioned version of the API anyway.

### SOUpdater - UnRefresh! (1.2)

[image]

#### App

(Chrome-Extension)

### About

**SOUpdater** is a chrome extension that helps in plugging-in questions asked in stackoverflow in a sidebar and update it frequently without the user requiring to refresh the page. It also provides for unobtrusive notification, highlighted-interesting questions (tags favored by the user in his/her profile) and no.of questions to display in the sidebar.

Being a lazy person I always wanted to avoid refreshing the page to get new questions. Wanted to avoid hitting f5 every so m seconds. So this add-on :).

### License

(Not Sure what should I put here :P. Suggest me if there is any!)

### Download

Dead link: <del>https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gfckpgnpcdclpenmahicjocnjhloekel/</del>

### Platform

Google Chrome.

## Contact

ajainarayanan- I am available at ajainarayanan@gmail.com

### Code

Javascript,HTML5,Google-Chrome.

Comment: I've embedded the image in your post for you.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Thanks. My bad, I should have done that.

Comment: If you are considering putting your extension under an open-source license, I strongly suggest the [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html).

Comment: I thought about it.. I can specify it here, but I have not added to each of my code files. Will do it in sometime.. Thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: P.S. You might also want to remove the `/publish-accepted?hl=en` from the end of your link since it displays a message at the top of the page.